# How to have python wait until an Excel Macro/Refresh is done

Tags: python, excel, win32com, vba

I am using Python to run a macro in excel. and I want Python to close excel. The macro refreshes a data connection in excel which can be slow.

How do I have python wait until the refresh is done to close. This is what I am using, I need something before the xl.Quit that will wait until the refresh in macro is done????

```
 import win32com.client
 import os

 xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
 wb = xl.workbooks.open("X:\Backoffice\Options Trading\BloombergRate.xlsm")
 xl.Visible = True
 xl.run("Refresh")
 xl.Quit()
```

Wait ways can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your `Refresh` macro to set [`QueryTable.BackgroundQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839478.aspx) property to `False`.  This should cause the macro to block until it is done.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to set up a macro to run this. win32com has a native method to refresh all data connections.

```
import win32com.client
import os

xl = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
wb = xl.workbooks.open("X:\Backoffice\Options Trading\BloombergRate.xlsm")
xl.Visible = True
wb.RefreshAll()
xl.Quit()
```

Comment: What about setting background refresh to False using Python's win32com model?