# How do I make an Excel RefreshAll wait to close until it finishes refreshing (python)?

Tags: python, excel, refresh, win32com

I've found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296591/how-do-i-make-an-excel-refreshall-wait-to-close-until-finished) but I couldn't resolve my problem

I have an excel that doesn't have a pivot table, so the command "table.BackgroundQuery = False" in the code below is never excecuted. How can I solve the problem regarding my question in a Excel file without a Pivot table?

```
import win32com.client
fileName = "C:\\Users\Davide\Desktop\Refresh.xlsx"
wb = xl.workbooks.open(fileName)
xl.Visible = True
#wb.RefreshAll()

for sheet in wb.Sheets:
    print(sheet.name)
    for table in sheet.QueryTables:
    print("Found a query table on %s called %s" % (sheet.name, table.name))
    table.BackgroundQuery = False
    if table.Refresh() == True:
        print("Query table %s refreshed!" % table.name)
    else:
        print("Query table %s FAILED to refresh." % table.name)
for i in range(1,5):
    try:
        print("Found pivot table #%s called %s" % (i,sheet.PivotTables(i).Name))
        if sheet.PivotTables(i).RefreshTable()==True:
            print("Refreshed pivot table %s" % sheet.PivotTables(i).Name)
        else:
            print("FAILED to refresh pivot table %s" % sheet.PivotTables(i).Name)
    except:
        print("No pivot table #%s found on sheet %s" % (i,sheet.Name))
        break
wb.Save()
xl.Quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by wait to close?

Comment: I need the refresh process (in Excel) to be concluded before python executes the command "xl.Quit()".

Comment: Not sure if this helps but here's what I do. I use Power Query to load the table into a sheet, and also enable load to the Data Model. At this point, running wb.RefreshAll() waits and only runs the next line once the data is loaded. This doesn't seem to work with xl.Visible = False though.